# Change the size of the button with size of the window in vb.net

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, resize

How do I connect the size of any button in the form to the size of the window so that it would change proportionally to the size of the window?

I went through these:

1. [How to: Anchor Controls on Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
2. [AutoSize Property Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171729%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

All the buttons I had on the window I applied proper anchoring and set auto size to true, but as I increase the size of the window, the size of the buttons doesn't increase with them.

Comment: Not really the right place for this question, you should try Stackoverflow.com, however I believe to do what you asked you have to do something like add a resize event handler to the form and programatically change the size of the button depending on the dimensions of the form. Also docking controls to a form will also cause them to resize with the form (this can be done in the properties window in VS).

Comment: This is a question for Stack Overflow, but you'll need to provide a lot more information on what you've tried etc.

Comment: This kind of proportional sizing can create shockingly ugly UI's.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set the `Anchor` property to match what you're trying to accomplish. If you want the width to update, set it to 'Left,Right'; for height, set it to 'Top,Bottom'.

The `AutoSize` property just tells the control to resize to fit **it's own content**, so that's not really applicable to what you're trying to do. Setting the `AutoSize` property to true overrides/cancels out the resizing that would happen with the correct anchoring.